# Shapeless : Prepend. Implicit not found

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless

I'm trying to use shapeless to accumulate easily objects in a type safe manner.

The problem is when I want to concat (`:::`) two `HList`. I'm encountering a newbie (it seems at least) problem. It misses a `Prepend` implicit instance in the context.

However, looking into `hlist.scala`, I can see that generic `implicit def` are defined in the objects `Prepend` and `PrependAux`.

Adding `import Prepend` and `import PrependAux` manually didn't change anything (obviously...).

So here the code reduced to the minimum:

```
enter code here

import shapeless._
import HList._
import Prepend._
import PrependAux._

object test {

  val a:HList = 1 :: 4 :: "A" :: HNil
  val b:HList = "R" :: false :: HNil

  val c:HList = a ::: b   // <<<<<<<<<<< NEEDS A Prepend in the context 

}
```

In the console now:

```
[error]     test.scala:10: could not find implicit value for parameter prepend: shapeless.Prepend[shapeless.HList,shapeless.HList]
[error]     val c:HList = a ::: b   // this needs an implicit Prepend in the current context
```

What should burn my eyes?

thanks

**EDIT**

A little update to re-complexify a bit the real problem, because to vulgarization was to strong before.

Here is the kind of thing that I would be able to do:

```
case class A[L<:HList](a:L) { 
  def doSmth[C <:HList](c:C) = a ::: c 
}
```

So I've not the access to the real type, only I know that they are *HList* s.

Comment: the only answers has been update also. and it still work. The thing that was missing in my solution was, apparently, the scalac option...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The up-casts to `HList` are the problem here. There's almost nothing you can do with a plain old `HList` (apart from adding new elements to it).

You can either provide more informative type annotations:

```
val a: Int :: Int :: String :: HNil = 1 :: 4 :: "A" :: HNil
val b: String :: Boolean :: HNil = "R" :: false :: HNil
val c: Int :: Int :: String :: String :: Boolean :: HNil = a ::: b
```

Or just let the types be inferred, which is usually much more convenient:

```
val a = 1 :: 4 :: "A" :: HNil
val b = "R" :: false :: HNil
val c = a ::: b
```

---

In response to your comment: you can do what you want if you make sure you've got the evidence you need (note that I've assumed that `a: A` was a typo for `a: L`, and that you'll need `-Ydependent-method-types` for this to work):

```
case class A[L <: HList](a: L) {
  def doSmth[C <: HList](c: C)(implicit p: Prepend[L, C]) = a ::: c
}
```

In general you can just look at the implicits that are necessary for the operations you're using, and then include them on your method.

Comment: Thx, you're perfectly right (so I validated of course). Actually my example has reduced too much the problem. Because my problem resides in the kind of stuffs (a bit less reduced): `case class A[L<:HList](a:A) { def doSmth[C <:HList](c:C) = a ::: c  }`. What do think ?

Comment: You're right for the typo! Sorry about that. Thx for the update (I'll update the question as well). Actually I did it, and probably that I needed the option you talked about to have this working. Thx again, I'll git it a try soon.

Comment: It works.. I've put the scalac option, and in some cases defined what is the "shape" of the HList and now works. THX